# Pandas multisheet concat and multidimensional grouper

Tags: python, excel, pandas, concatenation

hey guys following problem
I have multiple sheets in excel that represent sensors with values.
The format of each sheet will contain always Timestamp and the number of coordinates.
All the sensors work on different frequencies which means the amount of data is dissimilar
example:

[image]

As you can see because the frequency of the first sensor is 10 times higher every 10th Timestamp matches.
I wanna merge multiple sheets so that the result looks first like following

[image]

And then it should look like this:

[image]

So to make it clear, I want to align two sensors based on Timestamp columns, and for the sensor that had lower frequency simply copy the same Timestamp and same values until the next matching timestamp has been reached. I would like to be able to do this with an undetermined number of sheets

pd.concat((current_data[frame] for frame in current_data.keys()),axis=1)
when I use this command I get
[image]

when I try to use .groupby('Timestamp') i get following error
ValueError: Grouper for 'Timestamp' not 1-dimensional

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I'm looking for this same thing...

Comment: No, I'm still searching, how about you now?

Comment: I was able to merge with NaN for all numbers using pandas.merge() function and "outer" mode. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html - EDIT: I preferred the pandas instead of the pandas.Dataframe version where you specify both frames as parameters, so edited to link to that API documentation.